# Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension : Long running operation

Tags: powershell, azure, encryption, azure-virtual-machine

While trying to encrypt a VM, I am getting the below error:

> Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension : Long running operation failed
>   with status 'Failed'. ErrorCode: VMExtensionProvisioningError
>   ErrorMessage: VM has reported a failure when processing extension
>   'AzureDiskEncryptionForLinux'. Error message: "Enable failed.".
>   StartTime: 11/15/2017 11:12:30 AM EndTime: 11/15/2017 11:14:38 AM
>   OperationID: 004051ca-bf73-4a37-a145-5e0ac30bc30a Status: Failed At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGrou ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension], ComputeCloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Extension.AzureDiskEncryption.SetAzureDiskEncryptionExtensionCommand

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using  Azure PowerShell version 1.1.0?

Comment: No latest powershell version only.

Comment: Azure poweshell 5.0.0?

Comment: What is the OS of your VM?  Azure Disk Encryption is supported on limited OS in Gallery.

Comment: With Ubuntu..I  have encrypted the VM. In the OS disk,it is showing that encryption is enabled. But for attached disks it is showing just '-'.Not sure whether encryption enabled for the disk or not.How can I confirm it

Comment: There is a list of Azure Disk Encryption supported scenarios :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption#prerequisites  Check if that your OS version is supported. Please let me known if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue. The reason was i was not changing the access policy of the key vault.
use this command to change the access policy first and then execute the command for encryption.
`Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $KeyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -EnabledForDiskEncryption`
and then check the policy with the following command 
`(Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $keyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $rgName).EnabledForDiskEncryption` it should return true.